# Iphone+FlipView Using presentmodalview controller not being called

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi guys I have written the following function which has been attached to a `UIButton`s Action.It gets called & works as desires when Button Clicked but doesnt work when called elsewhere in the class.

```
-(void)punchcardDetailButtonClicked{
    NSLog(@"punchcardDetailButtonClicked");
    PunchCardDetailsViewController *punchCardDetailsViewController=[[PunchCardDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PunchCardDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nvcLocation=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:punchCardDetailsViewController];
    punchCardDetailsViewController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    UIColor* navBarColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0 green:99.0/255.0 blue: 64.0/255.0 alpha:0.0];
    nvcLocation.navigationBar.tintColor = navBarColor;
    [self presentModalViewController:nvcLocation animated:YES];
    [nvcLocation release];
    [punchCardDetailsViewController release];
```

}

I have called it in the same class using `[self punchcardDetailButtonClicked]` but this doesn't work as desired. Although,the `NSlog` gets printed in both cases.

Comment: Please post some more code from the part where you do the call of `[self punchcardDetailButtonClicked]` . From where (i.e. is it the main thread?) do you do the call  ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to present view Controller, use this

`[self presentModalViewController:punchCardDetailsViewController animated:YES];`

not Navigation Controller , not this

```
[self presentModalViewController:nvcLocation animated:YES];
```

and you are adding your view controller as root view controller to navigation controller, i think you can push that controller instead of giving transition style

and about `[self punchcardDetailButtonClicked]` check that whether you have declared this method in .h file before calling it

Comment: I don't think that answers the question in any way. 1.: it works when called from the Button. 2. It's executed when called programmatically  (the log statements tells it).